# Base class variable does not store value which is set by Derived class

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am new to python.
Base class/python file(Base.py).

```
SESSION_ID = ""

def m1():
    print "SESSION_ID in base: ",SESSION_ID
```

Derived class(Derived.py)

```
from Base import *

class Derived():
    def m2(self):
        global SESSION_ID
        SESSION_ID = 10
        print "SESSION_ID in derived: ", SESSION_ID

def main():
    c2 = Derived()
    c2.m2()
    m1()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I execute Derived.py file below is the output:

```
SESSION_ID in derived:  10
SESSION_ID in base:
```

I want the value which is set in m2() to be reflected in m1(). So the expected output is:

```
SESSION_ID in derived:  10
SESSION_ID in base:  10
```

Can you please help?

Comment: There is no class called "Base", only a module. I think you may have seen an example somewhere that was easy to misunderstand.

Comment: `global` in Python only means global to the module the code is in, not all modules used. This means there are two `SESSION_ID` variables, one for the `Base.py` module/script and a separate one for the `Derived.py` script. BTW, your code isn't following the naming conventions outlined in [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions),  including the naming of script/module files—which I **strongly** suggest you take the time to read it and begin following.

Comment: You `Derived` class doesn't derive from anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global variable in a module is merely an attribute (i.e. a member 
entity) of that module.

As result of that when you use `import *`, the new local module global `SESSION_ID` is created, so the SESSION_ID in the base is immune to the changes you are doing in the Derived.

Basically, modifying `base.SESSION_ID` don't require usage of the `global` statement in the `Derived.py`, adjusting `import` is enough, see code below:

```
from settings import base


class Derived():
    def m2(self):
        base.SESSION_ID = 10
        print "SESSION_ID in derived: ", base.SESSION_ID

def main():
    c2 = Derived()
    c2.m2()
    base.m1()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can you please explain the import statement? What is settings?

Answer (score 2):

Your `Derived` class is **not** derived from anything inside `Base.py`. Here, you are just calling a basic function from `Base` from within `Derived`, nothing more.

Here is an example on [class inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) in Python3 :

```
>>> class Base():
>>>   SESSION = 42
>>>
>>>   def print_session(self):
>>>     print("Base session : %d" % self.SESSION)
>>>
>>> class Derived(Base):
>>>   SESSION = 999
>>>
>>> d = Derived()
>>> d.print_session()
Base session : 999
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using global and class-scoped variables if at all possible.  These can make your program harder to understand (if something else changes a global underneath you it's hard to notice) and test (you need to reset all global state between every test; it's often easier to just create new empty state).

I might restructure this example by creating a state object:

```
class State:
  def __init__(self):
    self.session_id = ''
```

And then making that explicitly be a property, say, of the base class:

```
class Base:
  def __init__(self, state):
    self.state = state

  def m1(self):
    print("SESSION_ID in base: " + str(self.state.session_id))

class Derived(Base):
  def m2(self):
    self.state.session_id = '10'
    print("SESSION_ID in derived: " + str(self.state.session_id))
```

Then in your main function you need to explicitly create the state object and pass it in

```
def main():
  state = State()
  c2 = Derived(state)
  c2.m2()
  c2.m1()
```

But, critically, your tests don't need to worry about state leakage

```
def test_m2():
  state = State()
  obj = Derived(state)
  obj.m2()
  assert state.session_id == '10'

def test_m1():
  state = State()
  obj = Base(state)
  obj.m1()
  # If the session ID was a global or a class variable,
  # you'd get a different result if m2() was called or not
  assert state.session_id == ''
```